# Has Jason Fry publicly discussed the links between his short story Rendezvous Point and the Star Wars X-Wing series?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, behind-the-scenes, the-empire-strikes-back

Jason Fry wrote a short story titled *Rendezvous Point* in the short story collection *The Empire Strikes Back : From a Certain Point of View*.

This story cover Wedge Antilles reforming an X-Wing squadron after the losses suffered at the battle of Hoth.

This story shares a lot of homages to the X-wing novel series by Michael A. Stackpole and Aaron Allston that was published in the mid 1990's.

**Has Jason Fry every public discussed or acknowledge these homages to the earlier texts?**

These homages include:

- Both cover Wedge Antilles and Wes Janson forming an X-Wing squadron.
- In the short story Wedges R5 unit, makes a screeching noise making it sound like a agitated mynock. In the X-wing novels Wedges R5 unit was called Mynock.
- In both Janson is a prankster whose pranks are turned around on him.
- In both Wedge meets with a senior alliance figure to discuss operations (Mon Mothma in the short story and Gial Ackbar in the novels)
- In the novels Wedge alluded to having lost people he loves back on Corellia. In the novels his parents were killed by pirates at their fuelling depo.
- Both squadrons are made of an eclectic bunch of characters with some of them being misfits.
- Tomer Darpen appears in both short story and novels, and in both is seen as a shady character.
- In the short story Janson says the squadron should be called *Reject Squadron*. In the novels Wraith Squadron had several silly potential names before the final name was chosen.
- Both story's make use of simulation tanks for pilot training.
- In the short story Janson taunts Wedge with the phrase *Hub Grub Commander Hub Grub*. In the novels Janson taunts Wedge with the phrase *Jub Jub Commander Jub Jub*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't need to leave the story to find evidence that this is a clear homage to *X-Wing* series of novels by Aaron Allston and Michael A. Stackpole, since one of the characters mentioned is [Aron Polstak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aron_Polstak#cite_note-Rendezvous_Point-1)(!)

> Janson blew out his breath in frustration. “There aren’t many
> candidates, boss. Even with this Contessa of yours giving us all the
> personnel records. And why can’t she fly with us?”
>
> “The chancellor needs her to coordinate our overall starfighter
> defenses. And she’s got her own squadron to put back together.”
>
> “Well, that makes the pickings even slimmer. **I’d take Aron Polstak in
> a heartbeat, but Double-M’s got him on special assignment.** At least
> there’s Will Scotian. He’s flown with us, which makes him a definite.”

Out of universe, he's acknowledged that this is all very much intentional.

> **Jason Fry:** *So glad to see this. **I really wanted "Rendezvous Point" to be a tip of
> the cap from a fan and fellow author to Mike Stackpole and Aaron
> Allston**, one that celebrates the characters they created and the
> stories they crafted. Those stories brought me and many others so much
> joy.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via twitter](https://twitter.com/jasoncfry/status/1326239284534403077?lang=ar-x-fm)</sup></sub>